# Calculation Slider to increase after certain number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I have a slider that calculates (x * y) * 35. I want to make it so if (x * y) = >200 then it should be:

(x * y) * 35 + 5

But the calculations should only come after 200. For example:

```
x = 1
y = 50
z = 1750

x = 1
y = 200
z = 7000

x = 1
y = 201
z = 7040
```

So basically the number should increase by 35 until x * y = >200, then it should increase by 40.

This is my code:
html

```
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Elever: <span id="saleprice"></span></p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="sale">
    </div>


    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Paket sålda: <span id="commission"></span></p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="1" class="slider" id="commission_range" step="1">
    </div>


    <div class="outputbox">
      <p>Totalt: <span id="total_commission" ></span>:-</p>
    </div>
```

css

```
    .slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outputbox p{
    padding-top:20px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: Dosis;
}
.slidecontainer p{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Dosis;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
var comslider = document.getElementById("sale");
var comoutput = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var salep = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var comp = document.getElementById("commission");
var totalout = document.getElementById("total_commission");
var slider = document.getElementById("commission_range");
var output = document.getElementById("commission");

comoutput.innerHTML = comslider.value; // Display the default slider value
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
comslider.oninput = function() {
  comoutput.innerHTML = this.value;
  calcTotalCommission();
}

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  calcTotalCommission();
}

// Update the totalCommision number with current values
function calcTotalCommission(price, percentage) {
  var total = parseInt(salep.innerHTML) * (parseFloat(comp.innerHTML) * 35);
  totalout.innerHTML = total.toFixed(0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: seems like an if/else is what you need???

Answer (score 0):

Add an IF check after getting the total. If total is greater than 200, then run function again with multiple of 40, otherwise if not greater than 200 server total as normal.

```js
var comslider = document.getElementById("sale");
var comoutput = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var salep = document.getElementById("saleprice");
var comp = document.getElementById("commission");
var totalout = document.getElementById("total_commission");
var slider = document.getElementById("commission_range");
var output = document.getElementById("commission");

comoutput.innerHTML = comslider.value; // Display the default slider value
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
comslider.oninput = function() {
  comoutput.innerHTML = this.value;
  calcTotalCommission();
}

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  calcTotalCommission();
}

// Update the totalCommision number with current values
function calcTotalCommission(price, percentage) {
  var total = parseInt(salep.innerHTML) * (parseFloat(comp.innerHTML) * 35);
  // Check if total is greater than 200 and get new total if so
  if (total > 200) {
    total = parseInt(salep.innerHTML) * (parseFloat(comp.innerHTML) * 40);
  }
  totalout.innerHTML = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.outputbox p {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Dosis;
}

.slidecontainer p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Dosis;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Elever: <span id="saleprice"></span></p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="sale">
</div>


<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Paket sålda: <span id="commission"></span></p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="1" class="slider" id="commission_range" step="1">
</div>


<div class="outputbox">
  <p>Totalt: <span id="total_commission"></span>:-</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's close to what I'm trying to achieve. What I'm looking for is after the total value is 7000, next step should be 7040 and not 7035 or 8040. In your case it's 8040 because it recalculates the whole equation. I just want it to increase after 7000. Not the total itself. I hope you understand.